# Pydantic2. Can I parse float from string with comma?

Tags: python, pydantic

Data from my class can consist bad converted data like this: {..., "balance": "13,7"}

How can I automatically fix all values, but only for float fields?

```
class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    balance: float
    weight: float
    # ... other float strings
```

Comment: No, my question is: do all floating point number in your input have a comma? Or are there floating point numbers with periods as well?

Comment: Some numbers are with dots =/
Anarchy.
Example:
{"modified": 1611.357, "cost_per_km": "75,12", "company_id": 578}

Answer (score 0):

I make a validator. I hope it will work fine

```
class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    balance: float
    weight: float
    # ... other float strings


    @model_validator(mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def fix_float(cls, data: dict) -> dict:
        for k, v in data.items():
            if issubclass(float, cls.__annotations__[k]) and isinstance(v, str):
                data[k] = v.replace(',', '.')
        return data
```